# How can I parse json data with sql query in PHP classes?

Tags: php, android, sql, json, parsing

I have a php json creater. That is a web service and I use it in android. I have sql datas, classes and would like run querys in clasess.

This is my json parser without classes.

```
<?php
 /$sql_query = blabla{

   $dolaplar= array();
    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
      // printf ("%d - %s - %s\n", $obj->id, $obj->tanim, $obj->tipi);
        $dolaplar[]= $obj;
    }
    $kodlanmis= json_encode($dolaplar);
    echo $kodlanmis;

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

?>
```

And It's json data.

```
[
{
malzeme_id: "9",
malzeme_adi: "10 kohm direnc",
malzeme_miktari: "580"
},
{
malzeme_id: "8",
malzeme_adi: "Hdmi Kablosu",
malzeme_miktari: "128"
},
{
malzeme_id: "7",
malzeme_adi: "Kirmizi Led",
malzeme_miktari: "-653"
}
]
```

Here is classes.

```
<?php
class A {
    public $Message = "Success";
    public $MessageInfo = "";
    public $Payload = array();

    function  __construct(){
        for ( $i=3; $i-->0;){
            array_push($this->Payload, new B);
        }
    }
}

class B {
    public $a = 3;
    public $b = 4;
}

echo json_encode(new A);
?>
```

And I would like to see like that json data.

```
{
Message: "Success",
MessageInfo: "",
Payload: [
{
 malzeme_id: "9",
 malzeme_adi: "10 kohm direnc",
 malzeme_miktari: "580"
},
{
malzeme_id: "8",
malzeme_adi: "Hdmi Kablosu",
malzeme_miktari: "128"
},
{
malzeme_id: "7",
malzeme_adi: "Kirmizi Led",
malzeme_miktari: "-653"
}
]
}
```

I am not really good about php. Is it possible ?

Comment: Well, you need to pass the payload data in some way to Class A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a parameter to your Class A and Class B constructors:

**Class A:**

```
class A {
    public $Message = "Success";
    public $MessageInfo = "";
    public $Payload = array();

    function  __construct($data){
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            array_push($this->Payload, new B($d));
        }
    }
}
```

**Class B:**

```
class B {
    public function __construct($data) {
        array_walk($data, function($value, $key){
            $this->$key = $value;
        });
    }
}
```

Then your call would look something like:

```
$data = $dolapla // ???
echo json_encode(new A($data));
```